# What is the error when executing a FLATLIST?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-elements

When executing sends me the following error, do you know what I'm doing wrong?
I used the code that is published

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.
>
> Check the render method of FlatListDemo.
>
> This error is located at: in FlatListDemo (at withExpoRoot.js:22) in
>   RootErrorBoundary (at withExpoRoot.js:21) in ExpoRootComponent (at
>   renderApplication.js:34) in RCTView (at View.js:44) in RCTView (at
>   View.js:44) in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
>
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5630:10
>   in createFiberFromElement
>   node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\oss\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9710:8
>   in reconcileSingleElement ... 21 more stack frames from framework
>   internals

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";

class FlatListDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: 1,
        seed: this.state.seed + 1,
        refreshing: true
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round />;
  };

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar
              title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
              subtitle={item.email}
              avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.email}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={50}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}

export default FlatListDemo;
```

Comment: Hello, are you sure that `roundAvatar` is working on `ListItem` ? can you try to remove it and compile again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were following this tutorial on medium https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-build-a-react-native-flatlist-with-realtime-searching-ability-81ad100f6699

Unfortunately this tutorial was written at a time before the `react-native-elements` were upgraded to `v1.0.0`. When `react-native-elements` was upgraded several components were dropped, and others were changed. For a full list of them you should see this [blog post](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/blog/2019/01/27/1.0-release.html) on their website. It is **too** long to replicate here but I will repeat the parts relevant to your specific situation.

## List

This have been removed and is what is probably causing the big error that you are seeing as you are trying to import something that doesn't exist anymore.

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/blog/2019/01/27/1.0-release.html#list

> `List` **component has been removed!** `List` was just a regular React Native
>   View with some small margin styles. It wasn't actually needed to use
>   the `ListItem` component. Instead we recommend using the `FlatList` or
>   `SectionList` components from React Native which function both as Views
>   and also displaying items, pull to refresh and more.

## ListItem

`roundAvatar` and `avatar`have been dropped, and are no longer in use.

https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/blog/2019/01/27/1.0-release.html#listitem

> `avatar`, `avatarStyle`, `avatarContainerStyle`, `roundAvatar`, and
>   `avatarOverlayContainerStyle` removed. Avatars can now be customized
>   using the `rightAvatar` and `leftAvatar` props which can either render a
>   custom element or an object that describes the props from Avatar.

---

## Solution

You have two choices.

1. Downgrade to `v0.19.1`
2. Refactor your code for `v1.0.0`

### Downgrade

The simplest (though this may not work as there may be compatibility issues with newer versions of react-native) is to downgrade your version of `react-native-elements`.

You can do that by running `npm uninstall react-native-elements`

and then reinstall the specific version `npm install react-native-elements@0.19.1`

You can see a full list of the `v0.19.1` components here https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/0.19.1/overview.html

### Refactor

The other choice, and probably the better choice though arguably it will require more work, is to refactor your code so that it uses the new components from `v1.0.0`.
You can see a full list of the `v1.0.0` components here https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/overview.html

Comment: effectively, after searching everywhere I realized that I did not require the list component, I will publish the solution for people who have the same problem as me, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

As Andres says, there are properties of react-native elements that changed therefore I will publish the code that in my case worked.

```
        import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { View, Platform, Image, Text,  FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
    import { ListItem, List } from "react-native-elements";

    class FlatListDemo extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          loading: false,
          data: []
        }
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }

      makeRemoteRequest = () => {
        const url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=1&page=1&results=20';
        this.setState({ loading: true });

        fetch(url)
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(res => {
            this.setState({
              data: res.results,
              loading: false,
            });
          });
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <View>

            <FlatList
              data={this.state.data}
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
                <ListItem
                title={
                  <View >
                    <Image style={{height:50}} source={require('./src/img/recarga.jpg')}>
                    </Image>
                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                  </View>
                }
                subtitle={item.email}
                />
              )}
              keyExtractor={item=>item.email}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    export default FlatListDemo;
```